# Is there a matrix math library that is good to use alongside OpenGL to keep track of primitive co-ordinates for collision detection

Tags: math, opengl, matrix, collision-detection

Matrix math library that is good to use alongside OpenGL to keep track of primitive co-ordinates.

Does such a thing exist? Is this the best way to track my objects for use in collision detection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't describe your situation very much but I'm assuming that you are making some game or simulation application?

I would suggest you use a physics engine, like [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) or [ODE](http://www.ode.org/), from the start. This way you will get a properly optimized matrix library plus well tested collision detection and handling. Using some other general-purpose matrix math library may seem easier at first glance. However it will probably be less adapted to your needs and will surely be a mess to replace with a physics engine if you decide to use one later on.

You don't have to use all the fancy features of the physics engine right away. In fact you could very well just use the matrix and vector implementation and skip the rest until later.

Comment: Thanks, I have taken this approach using Chipmunk Physics :)

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is simply for rendering the objects from your data store, your physics/collision library will already have matrices for all the objects within it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is such thing. Maybe this helps to clarify a few things:
http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=30